# Ubuntu 20.04.1 doesnt boot stuck on initramfs

Tags: boot, kernel, encryption, initramfs

I am having this problem. After updating and upgrading the new kernel loads up which is 5.15.0-52 and it doesnt boot. Stuck on initramfs. While the old kernel which is 5.15.0-48 still boots up just fine. It is FDE and there is no way to boot i tried everything i find on google. I was hoping someone here can help me out finding a fix for this. Thanks.

Edit. Forgot to add the fstab and crypttab are empty too after update to 5.15.0-52

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try rebuilding `initramfs` images for all installed kernels:
`sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`

Then run `sudo update-grub` to update the Grub bootloader entries.