# initramsfs: globally duplicate id for nsid 1. Kernel Ubuntu 22.04 with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic

Tags: boot, kernel, 22.04, initramfs

[image]

Hey
I'm pretty weak with linux.... I am currently using ubuntu 22.04.
After updating my ubuntu do not boot (Kernel linux 5.19.0-32-generic)
but on older (Linux 5.15.0-43-generic) it starts.

Do you know how to solve this?

EDIT: I forgot to mention - I reinstalled my system once.
Tried: update initramfs -> update grub, reistallation many times (smth else option), grub manager, kernel manager

ENDING LOG: I gave myself a break. I installed bionic beaver and upgraded to focal fossa. I had to go back to work. Thank you for support!

Comment: It looks like the `5.19.0-32-generic` didn't install correctly.  Boot with the 5.15 and reinstall it.

Comment: @Pilot6 I reinstalled my ubuntu! Forgot to menton it.

Comment: The message shows that UUID is wrong in `fstab`. You did something wrong.

Comment: @user68186 Its not help. Firsty i have update system and error occurs. I have tried update-initrams but it not help. Next, i rinstalled system with update.

Comment: You need to `update-initramfs` for all kernels, then do `update-grub`. Check if [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440682/134479) answers your question.

Comment: @zwets not help...

Comment: Seems to me a duplicated of this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1489393/alert-uuid-xxxx-does-not-exist-dropping-to-a-shell-ubuntu-installation-drive/1489450#1489450