# ALERT! UUID=XXXX does not exist. Dropping to a shell. Ubuntu installation drive is not being detected

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my NVMe SSD however it doesn't seem to find the SSD I installed Ubuntu on. I have Windows installed on my 2nd SSD and I'm also very new to Ubuntu. Here are the errors I get when booting into it.

```
    nvme nvme1: globally duplicate IDs for nsid 1
    nvme nvme1: VID:DID 1dbe:5216 model: MKNSSDTS512GB-D8 firmware:2.0
    nvidia-gpu 0000:26:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
    ucsi_ccg 0-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
    ucsi_ccg 0-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
    usbhid 5-1.2:1.2: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
    Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:
    - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
     - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
    - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
    ALERT! UUID=fa525e4b-5faa-46eb-bbfe-0c53dac962fa does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
    BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
    Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Result of running blkid

```
    /dev/nvmeon1p2: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="EC5C56895C564E88" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="914de62e-99f3-454e-a292-fcb 
    /dev/nvme0n1p1: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="7aae8229-a17a-424e-aef0-9f603cc9a59d"
```

when running  cat /proc/cmdline

```
    BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic root=UUID=fa525e4b-5faa-46eb-bbfe-0c53dac962fa ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

When running cat /proc/modules

```
    hid_generic 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc04bb000
    usbhid 73728 0 - Live 0xffffffffc04ec000
    hid 176128 2 hid_generic,usbhid, Live 0xffffffffc0526000
    ucsi_ccg 24576 0 - Live 0xffffffffc04e5000
    typec_ucsi 53248 1 ucsi_ccg, Live 0xffffffffc04d7000
    nvme 61440 0 - Live 0xffffffffc04c7000
    typec 106496 1 typec_ucsi, Live 0xffffffffc0674000
    r8169 114688 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0637000
    nvme_core 204800 1 nvme, Live 0xffffffffc0556000 
    12c_nvidia_gpu 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0521000 
    ahci 49152 0 - Live 0xffffffffc050b000 
    xhci_pci 24576 0 - Live 0xffffffffc04b4000 
    crc32_pclmul 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffffc066b000 
    i2c_pi1x4 28672 0 - Live 0xffffffffc065e000
    i2c_ccgx_ucsi 16384 1 12c_nvidia_gpu, Live 0xffffffffc061d000 
    realtek 36864 0 Live Oxffffffffc060e000
    libahci 57344 1 ahci, Live 0xffffffffc05ee000
    xhci_pci renesas 20480 1 xhci-pci, Live 0xffffffffc05e6000 
    nvme_common 28672 1 nvme_core, Live 0xffffffffc05de000 
    umi 40960 0 - Live 0xffffffffc0500000
    gpio_amdpt 20480 0 Live 0xffffffffc04a4000
```

The SSD does pick up on the BIOS. I've tried multiple reinstalls, however it gives the same issue. There's about a 10% chance that it boots into Ubuntu fine. When it does, I ran `sudo blkid` and got this as a result.

```
    UUID="fa525e4b-5faa-46eb-bbfe-0c53dac962fa" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="11009117-55ca-4835-8ac3-4628878570db"
    /dev/nvme1n1p2: 
    /dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs" 
    /dev/loops: TYPE="squashfs" 
    /dev/loopé: TYPE="squashfs" 
    /dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs" 
    /dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs" 
    /dev/loope: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/nvmeinip1: UUID="FC05-12DF" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="750593d9-e3e5-4767-9c45-8fa6d6d5c4d8"
    /dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
    /dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
```

When removing my second SSD I am able to boot into Ubuntu fine. I don't know if this is valuable information, but both SSDs are identical, the same brand, same size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the error message, in the first screenshot, first row:

```
globally duplicated IDs for nsid 1
```

It appears that some SSD vendor devices has all the same ID (see: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/drivers/nvme/host?h=v5.19-rc8&id=1629de0e0373e04d68e88e6d9d3071fbf70b7ea8 and
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711739/globally-duplicate-ids-for-nsid). Try installing a more recent kernel, 6.2.x ... it should fix the problem. Please report if it works.

Comment: This worked I updated to the latest kernel following this GitHub https://github.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh. Updating my kernel for some reason disabled my 2nd screen and I noticed my graphics cards fans aren't spinning, but I'll do some of my own research on how to fix that. Thanks so much :)